# Python heapq replace is slower than pop and push?

Tags: python, performance, heap

So, I want to half the largest element of a list k times.

I implemented it with heapq, after multiplying everything with -1, to have a min-heap.

```py
def minStoneSum(self, piles: List[int], k: int) -> int:

    h = [-el for el in piles]
    heapq.heapify(h)

    for i in range(k):
        # version 1
        newmax = min(h) >> 1
        heapq.heapreplace(h, newmax)

        # version 2
        # newmax = heapq.heappop(h) >> 1
        # heapq.heappush(h, newmax)
    ...
```

At first, I was using `max()` to get the first item and `heapreplace`, because according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapreplace), they were faster:

> **heapq.heapreplace(heap, item)**
> ... This one step operation is more efficient than a heappop() followed by heappush() and can be more appropriate when using a fixed-size heap.

> **heapq.nsmallest(n, iterable, key=None)**
> ...
> Also, when n==1, it is more efficient to use the built-in min() and max() functions

However, when I run it with a large initial list and k, it takes very long (over 30s), and when I run the version with `heappop` and `heappush()` it runs very fast.

Is heapreplace really slower than heappop and heappush? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the documentation for `heapq.nsmallest` and the comment on using `min()`, does not refer to heaps but to iterables in general.

For heaps, the smallest element can be found by `h[0]`.

So, the reason that the first version is much slower, is because min() treats the heap like a normal list, and (I guess) uses O(n) per call.

After replacing `min(h)` with `h[0]`, it turns out that heapreplace is indeed a bit faster than calling heappop and heappush.